# using MS Access 2010, editing a form, 3 tables, one table is "one to many" and want to have query across one row

Tags: sql, ms-access

Example:
(using a comma, to show columns & "A_", "B_", "C_" to show tables)
I currently have...

A_John,  A_Doe,  B_MemStartDate, C_Date,

A_John,  A_Doe,  B_MemStartDate, C_Date,

A_John,  A_Doe,  B_MemStartDate, C_Date,

I would like Table "C" columns to be pulled by Course but shown as the "Date" column...  in other words, example, where Course = 1, use Date... etc...

The table would have each member's course history.

MemberID, CourseID, Date

JohnDoe, Course1, 10-10-13

JohnDoe, Course2, 10-11-13

JohnDoe, Course3, 10-12-13

The table C is the one to many of course, with the goal to show the date that the course was taken as I would title the columns with the 3 different courses I want to show...  (I want to pull only 3 different courses)

I would like to have them in a row...

A_John,  A_Doe,  B_Start Date, C_Course1Date, C_Course2Date, C_Course3Date

Sorry for the lack of experience in my question, but I usually get by with "copy/paste"...LOL

Keeping in mind I am using Access... can I do this?

---

Clarifying...  sorry don't know how to do tables in basic html so have commas

***Have this.***  Pulling from 3 different tables where the member# is unique and joined.

**MEMBER**, **STARTDATE**, **STATUS**, **COURSE**, **COURSEDATE**
JohnSmith, 08-01-2013, Active, Workshop1, 10-20-2013
JohnSmith, 08-01-2013, Active, Workshop2, 10-13-2013
JohnSmith, 08-01-2013, Active, Workshop3, 10-28-2013
LaraBentt, 12-01-2012, Inactive, Workshop1, 02-20-2012
LaraBentt, 12-01-2012, Inactive, Workshop2, 02-13-2012
LaraBentt, 12-01-2012, Inactive, Workshop3, 02-28-2012

***Want this...***

**MEMBER**, **STARTDATE**, **STATUS**, **WORKSHOP1**, **WORKSHOP2**, **WORKSHOP3**
JohnSmith, 08-01-2013, Active, 10-20-2013, 10-13-2013, 10-28-2013
LaraBentt, 12-01-2012, Inactive, 02-20-2012, 02-13-2012, 02-28-2012

***Tables columns are basically like this...***
Table 1 - tblMember (one - one)
**MEMBER**, **STARTDATE**
Table 2 - tblRegStatus  (one - one)
**MEMBER**, **STATUS**
Table 3  - tblCourses (one to many)
**MEMBER**, **COURSE**, **COURSEDATE**

Hope this explains it better!

Comment: It would be better if you explained the fields in each of your three tables, one at a time and then explained what outcome you wanted.  Using sample data can make things clear when you cannot find the words to explain it.

I took the time to answer what I *think* you are asking - if its not what you were asking, I can adjust my answer - but I thought its better than having your question sit unanswered... better to start the dialog

Comment: agreed, but I am not a programmer nor a database person.  I thought it would be ok to ask in this area... please let me know if I was wrong.  You did get the idea of it and I will try to do this through Access from the links you sent.    oh yeah, and thanks for your help.  :)

Comment: You can ask in this area.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic or http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask can be consulted for clarification.  Don't worry about your experience level - we all start somewhere.
I think your question is quite relevant to the area - its just not clear what you are asking for - its vague.   My suggestion was/is to write out example data.  Show what data you have (list table names and field names), and what data you want to end up with (show fields).  Take a look at my answer to see how I've listed the data we started with, and ended with.

Comment: Just tried to "clarify"... let me know if that is a better way to explain it from a beginner point of view?

Comment: Yes much better.  I've updated my answer.  Let me know if that's what you were after

Answer (score 0):

Your amendment to your question made it much more clear.

One of the problems you are going to encounter is if you have someone that has registered for the same course, twice.  There has to be the understanding that you are only showing the most recent registration per person.  Now that we understand that caveat - lets look at how you can build this.

The simplest way of building this is to change the query type from *Select* to *Crosstab*.  This is done through the Access interface.

For each of the fields in the query, set the Total and Crosstab values to:

```
MemberName:   Total = *Group By*   Crosstab = *Row Heading*
StartDate:    Total = *Group By*   Crosstab = *Row Heading*
Status:       Total = *Group By*   Crosstab = *Row Heading*
CourseName:   Total = *Group By*   Crosstab = *Column Heading*
CourseDate:   Total = *Max*        Crosstab = *Value*
```

This will result in query results such as:

```
MemberName  StartDate   Status     Biology     English        Math
----------  ---------   ------     -------     -------        ----
John        10/1/2013   Active                 11/14/2013     12/1/2013
Matthew     9/1/2013    Inactive   1/1/2013     
Peter       8/7/2013    Active     1/1/2013    4/1/2013 
Sam         1/14/2013   Inactive               11/14/2013   
William     5/19/2013   Active     1/1/2013    4/1/2013
```

The advantage to the crosstab is that it will automatically add columns as there is data.
You have to construct your query (the joins) to give you the data that you want however.   For example - do you want to show members that have no courses on the list?   Do you want to show courses that have no enrollment?

Microsoft has a page on using crosstab queries:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/make-summary-data-easier-to-read-by-using-a-crosstab-query-HA010229577.aspx

If you want to hard code your three columns, you can also manually pivot the data. Again - keep in mind that we are using the *Max* aggregate, so only the latest courses will show.  With a manual pivot you also need to remember that it will be limited to the data you are requesting.

Take your select query, right click and click "Totals" to show the Totals row.  You can also click on the Totals icon in the ribbon under Query Tools / Design.
Set up your three columns:

```
MemberName:   Total = *Group By*
StartDate:    Total = *Group By*
Status:       Total = *Group By*
```

Now add in a separate field for each course you wish to include.  In the "Field" definition enter the following.

```
Science: IIf([CourseName]="Science",[CourseDate],Null)
Biology: IIf([CourseName]="Biology",[CourseDate],Null)
Math: IIf([CourseName]="Math",[CourseDate],Null)
English: IIf([CourseName]="English",[CourseDate],Null)
```

Set the "Total" definition value to "Max".

That should get you the results you are looking for.